Diode directed into the negative terminal of a sinusoidal voltage source

If my V_in is a sinusoidal voltage, what would be the V_out?
I tried to plot this in ltspice, however, I ran into trouble on where to connect the ground, on what node should I use to extract V_in and V_out from.
I also tried to use basic diode analysis like assuming the diode is conducting and find out what should be the value of V_in for the current to flow from anode to cathode. But I don't know how to do that if it's on the negative side of the terminal.

Vout will be the same in both these scenarios: -

You can connect ground where you want but, I'd connect it at the negative node of Vout if trying to understand what Vout looks like.

Thank you so much! But can you explain further? like how?

Two simple components in series carry the same current no matter what their order appears to be schematically @hutaonewbiEEE.

I've moved the diode in the second image so that it carries the same current under all circumstances and that means it does the same job.
